# iPhone won’t turn on, lost all recovery info

Tags: iphone, icloud, security, apple-id, password

Two weeks ago my iPhone suddenly turned off on me. Now it won’t boot past a white screen with the Apple logo.

I took my iPhone to the Apple Store, but the Genius couldn’t help because my Apple ID has been locked, and I can’t remember my account password.

It’s been so many years since I setup my rescue email and security questions that I also forgot what those are.

What are my options?

Comment: Start at https://iforgot.apple.com - literally no-one else can help but Apple.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, security is on your phone for a very good reason, which is why it is strongly advised that you write down your apple ID info. The iPhone uses your Apple ID to secure multiple layers within the software stack on the iPhone, such that it is impossible for anyone or any tool to access your phone without your password. This is done on purpose, so that neither Apple, a bad guy or good guys acting like bad guys, can access your personal data.

This Apple Support article suggests that you can [wipe your iPhone](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204306), and start all over, losing your data. At least you do not lose the iPhone, and hopefully, you have that data elsewhere. However, there may be instances where even this won't help. Good luck

Comment: Assuming that Find my iPhone is turned on (otherwise the Apple Genius should have been able to help) wiping the phone will not be possible.